# Depend on a Project which has it's own dependences (Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio using Gradle I have `ProjectA` which relies on `ProjectB` but `Project B` relies on `Project C` and `Project D` like so...

`Project A
  .. Project B
    .. Project C
    .. Project D`

Using the current Gradle scripts I get the following **error**

```
Error:(22, 0) Project with path ':ProjectC:app' could not be found in project ':ProjectB:app'.
```

*Folder Structure*

```
.\workspace
    \ProjectA
        \app
        \build
        \gradle  
        \.gradle
        \.idea
    \ProjectB (same as A)
    \ProjectC (same as A)
    \ProjectD (same as A)`
```

*Project A settings.gradle*

```
include ':app', ':ProjectB:app'
project (':ProjectB:app').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../ProjectB/app')
```

*Project A Project build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*Project A Module build.gradle*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.movetogradle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':ProjectB:app')        
}
```

Project B knows it's dependancies C and D using the same method above.

I'm new to the whole gradle scene. Obviously in Eclipse (ANT) you would just say ProjectB is a library. We would like to keep them as seperate projects and not modules because when code changes in ProjectB, it gets used by all projects using B.

I can get `ProjectA` to build if I add references to `ProjectC` and `ProjectD` like I have with `ProjectB`.

How could I get `ProjectA` to depend on `ProjectB` without having to declare all of `ProjectB`s dependencies in `ProjectA`?

Answer (score 0):

When another project is included in a Gradle multi-project build, I'm pretty sure  that the `settings.gradle` file is not read for that project. (see [the Gradle documentation, chapter 56.2](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html))
In a multi-project build, you are expected to at least include all of the required projects in your root `settings.gradle` file, so in this case, ProjectA's `settings.gradle` I believe needs to include projects C and D in order for the build to work. A doesn't need to declare any more dependencies, but Gradle needs to be made aware of the projects in order to build them.